# How to display WorkFlow Assigned To Column in Document Library

Tags: workflow, column

I have setup a Workflow which works really great. I can see the Assigned To column when I check the progress of the task. I want to show this particular Assigned To column in the Document Library. How can I get this done? Any help would be greatly appreciated[image: ![Snap of what I want to achieve]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STBkH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a user column in the associated list and write back to it during your workflow to specify who it is assigned to since the list does not have visibility into the workflow or the workflow tasks by default.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!!